# MySQL Delete everything in a group with a specified keyword but the max

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete every row in a group of userIDs, with the keyword xyz, except for the one with the highest price.

I tried many snippets from SO and it still does not work.

I tried:

```
DELETE FROM 
  `table` t1 
WHERE 
  `keyword` = 'xyz' AND 
  `price` <> (
    SELECT 
      MAX(`price`) 
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        * 
      FROM 
        `table` t2 
      WHERE 
        `keyword` = 'xyz' AND 
        t2.user = user
     ) t3 
  )
```

But it also selects the one with the highest price, it also selects only a fraction of the rows which should be deleted

This one...

```
DELETE FROM 
  `table` AS zt 
WHERE 
  `keyword` = 'xyz' AND 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      `table` ex 
    WHERE 
      ex.user = zt.user AND 
      ex.price > zt.price
  );
```

Gives me the following error:

Unknown table field `zt.user` in where clause. If I add `INNER JOIN` it says unknown keyword .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mysql, you cannot delete from `table x` while using `table x` in a **dependent** inner query, even if you give them different aliases.

Your inner query **is** dependent, because you use `zt` or the non-aliased access on `user` of the outer query in the first example.

The easiest option on this is 2 querys: First, get IDs to delete, second delete them. (Implementation depends on your programing language)

With one query it is only possible if you use joins.

Update: It's not possible for all sort of inner queries at all (without joins, or without multiple queries).

Update II: There are options with nesting inner queries in other queries, while setting `derived_merge=off` - but this is really ugly, go for the join.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JOIN with a subquery:

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM `table` t1
JOIN (
    SELECT user, max(price) as price
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY user
) t2 ON t2.user = t1.user
    AND t2.price <> t1.price
WHERE t1.keyword = 'xyz'
```

It's possible that you need `WHERE keyword = 'xyz'` in the subquery. That depends on your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

What about try something like

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `keyword` = 'xyz' AND `price` NOT IN (SELECT MAX(`price`) FROM table)
```

It's pretty rude, but should work

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `keyword` = 'xyz' AND `primarykey` !=
 (SELECT `primarykey` FROM `table` WHERE `price` = (SELECT MAX(`price`) FROM 
 `table`) LIMIT 1);
```